# Debugging tomcat app with possible memory leak

Tags: java, tomcat

Situation - API application running on tomcat. Every time I hit the API end point the memory usage in 'top' goes up a fraction. After it passes ~35-40% (roughly a dozen requests) the load level goes from 1% to 40+% and the app becomes non-responsive (and tomcat / container must be restarted).

What I've done:
1. Taken heap dumps after 1 request and then 5-10 requests and compared these. The memory growth is not in any of my classes but rather in 'int[]' and 'java.lang'. I don't know enough about java memory mgmt to understand this situation.

2. I monitored thread count / growth using `ps -eLf`. Nothing to report.
3. Watched GC using `jstat -gc`. Output looks like this:

(start)

```
  S0C      S1C     S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC      MU     CCSC   CCSU       YGC   YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
  56832.0 57856.0  0.0   17266.5 157184.0 31716.8   546304.0   35573.4   40104.0 39112.5 4776.0 4474.5      7    1.669   2      0.251    1.921
```

(end - before I lose contact)

```
 S0C     S1C      S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC       MU      CCSC     CCSU       YGC     YGCT  FGC      FGCT     GCT
 28160.0 27648.0  0.0    0.0   217088.0  4693.9   546304.0   76262.8   404008.0 402586.8 139816.0 139470.6     40    2.595  13      2.859    5.455
```

- again - I don't know enough about java memory mgmt to really interpret these values. I can see that major garbage collection isn't taking *too much* time but is definitely occurring.

  4. Also tried (as a hail-mary) to use `-XX:+UseG1GC`. No real difference.
  5. As the usage values go wild Ive watched CPU %/ IOWait (via top). CPU stays rational and no measurable IOWait. Also looked at `top -H` with wchan.

Suggestions on other places to look? See something obvious here that Ive overlooked?

Running using Java 8. Latest Tomcat rev. CentOS 7. (test running in Docker).

---

## additional

Did some measurements using `jstat -class` and am curious about these values:

(start)

```
Loaded  Bytes .   Unloaded  Bytes     Time
121699 122371.1        4     3.4      31.34
```

(end)

```
Loaded  Bytes    Unloaded    Bytes    Time
194495 191761.7        4     3.4      39.20
```

Is this saying that my app has loaded an additional 70K classes and not unloaded any? Is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `jvisualvm` and connect remotely (by starting your tomcat instance with the correct jmx parameters https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/jmx_connections.html). Then you'll be able to see everything including heap memory, and much much more. In your case you might be running out of heap memory and the GC keeps on trying to free memory up but due to memory leak is not able to do so and this repeats indefinitely, the CPU being very busy.

Comment: CPU % stays within rational limits. The system usage values (5 min, 15 min, etc) are the ones that go very high.

Comment: the GC thread might be taking only 1 core and what do you mean by system usage?

Comment: Im referring to the values I get from `uptime` or `top`